# Makefile circular dependency dropped

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I am trying to create a makefile for my project, but while running it I am getting an error
like:

`make: Circular database.cpp <- database.cpp dependency dropped`

`make: database.cpp' is up to date.`

Here is my Makefile:

```
HEADERFILES = $(wildcard *.h)
CPPFILES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJFILES = $(patsubst %.cpp ,%.o ,$(wildcard *.cpp))
$(OBJFILES): $(CPPFILES) $(HEADERFILES)
    g++ -c -o $(OBJFILES) $(CPPFILES)
    ar rvs libdatabase.a $(OBJFILES)
```

I have only one `.cpp` and `.h` file. Please someone correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra space in your `patsubst` which is preventing a correct match, so that `OBJFILES` is "database.cpp". You can correct it like so:

```
OBJFILES = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o ,$(wildcard *.cpp))
```

But that still leaves you with a makefile that will fail badly when you add a second source file to the codebase. I suggest you do it this way:

```
$(OBJFILES): %.o : %.cpp $(HEADERFILES)
    g++ -c -o $@ $<
    ar rvs libdatabase.a $@
```

Comment: @MadScientist actually u modified my command $(CPPFILES) -> %.o : %.cpp what does %.o:%.cpp means could u please explain alittle bit clearly what % will do

Comment: Beta actually answered this question not me.  The best way to learn is to read the documentation, not ask on StackOverflow.  The form Beta is using is call a _static pattern rule_.  The section of the GNU make manual that describes them is http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html