# C Makefile with multiple files

Tags: makefile

I am attempting to write a makefile that compiles multiple files. Here is my attempt:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -ansi -Wall -g -O0 -Wwrite-strings -Wshadow \
    -pedantic-errors -fstack-protector-all
PROGS = myprog.o test1 test2 test3 test4 \

all: $(PROGS)

clean:
        rm -f *.o $(PROGS) *.tmp

$(PROGS): myprog.o

myprog.o: prog-implementation.h myprog.c myprog.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c myprog.c
memory_checker: memory_checker.o
    gcc -o memory_checker memory_checker.o
memory_checker.o: memory_checker.c memory_checker.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c memory_checker.c
test1: test1.o
    gcc -o test1 test1.o myprog.o
test1.o: test1.c myprog.h myprog.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c test1.c myprog.c
test2: test2.o
    gcc -o test2 test2.o myprog.o
test2.o: test2.c myprog.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c test2.c
test3: test3.o
    gcc -o test3 test3.o myprog.o
test3.o: test3.c myprog.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c test3.c
test4: test4.o
    gcc -o test4 test4.o myprog.o memory_checker.c
test4.o: test4.c myprog.h memory_checker.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c test4.c
```

As you can probably tell from the makefile, the main code is in myprog.c, which includes myprog.h and prog-implementation.h. I also have 4 tests for my code, the last of which has a memory_checker to ensure that I freed all dynamically allocated memory. The tests are where the main() methods are and are *.c files.

Whenever I attempt to use the makefile, it gives me the error

```
make: Circular myprog.o <- myprog.o dependency dropped.
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

All of my idents are with tabs and not spaces, so that is not the issue. I am also fairly certain there isn't any major problems with my code, so the makefile has to be my problem.

Comment: Have you tried looking for the error? I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324697/makefile-circular-dependency-dropped). It sounds interesting!

Comment: It looks like you've defined `$(PROGS)` to be dependent on `myprog.o` but `PROGS` also has that dependency. Just guessing.  This is WAY to complex.  make can define all object files for you in terms of all your C files using wildcards.  Just look for any tutorial.

Comment: If not for learning purposes, do not use Makefiles manually. Use a modern tool like cmake.

Comment: @AyberkÖzgür I disagree. `make` has a *lot* of flexibility and once you learned it, you can use it very efficiently.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I probably should have clarified that what I suggest is for building c/c++ code. There is little flexibility that can be provided by manual Makefile writing that can't be provided by a tool like cmake in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message should be pretty clear:

```
make: Circular myprog.o <- myprog.o dependency dropped.
```

It says that `myprog.o` depends on `myprog.o`. That is, to make `myprog.o`, it first has to make `myprog.o`, which is a logic error. The reason for it is this part in your `Makefile`:

```
PROGS = myprog.o test1 test2 test3 test4 \

....    

$(PROGS): myprog.o
```

The second line says that all `PROGS` depend on `myprog.o`. One of `PROGS` is `myprog.o`, so it now depends on itself.

To fix, remove `myprog.o` from the list of `PROGS`.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it

Answer (score 0):

This has many errors and needless complexity, so I'll just present you a better solution with some comments (it assumes you use *GNU make*):

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -ansi -Wall -g -O0 -Wwrite-strings -Wshadow \
    -pedantic-errors -fstack-protector-all

PROGS := test1 test2 test3 test4

# check these lists of object files needed for each binary, I extracted
# it from your rules in the question:
test1_OBJS := test1.o myprog.o
test2_OBJS := test2.o
test3_OBJS := test3.o myprog.o
test4_OBJS := test4.o myprog.o memory_checker.o
OBJS := $(sort $(test1_OBJS) $(test2_OBJS) $(test3_OBJS) $(test4_OBJS))

all: $(PROGS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.d $(PROGS) *.tmp

# the following rules link your final targets from the object files
# specified in the variables above:

test1: $(test1_OBJS)
    $(CC) -o$@ $^

test2: $(test2_OBJS)
    $(CC) -o$@ $^

test3: $(test3_OBJS)
    $(CC) -o$@ $^

test4: $(test4_OBJS)
    $(CC) -o$@ $^

# this automatically generates dependency files (with your headers)
%.d: %.c
    $(CC) -MM -MT"$@ $(@:.d=.o)" -MF$@ $(CFLAGS) $<

# and this includes them
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
endif

# finally, all you need is a pattern rule compiling your object files:

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o$@ $(CFLAGS) $<

.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: I tried using your makefile that you suggested, but still get the "nothing to be done for 'all'" error

Comment: but you DO have your source files (`test1.c`, `myprog.c`, etc) in the current directory, don't you?

Comment: Yes I do, all files are in the current directory

Comment: Well, maybe missing some *tab* characters when copying my Makefile, but it would work, I'm *pretty* sure about this...